# Pointer to Span and Memory

Tags: c#

The `CRC32DelimitedBufferWriter` below saves a pointer to each span or memory when it is requested by a caller. When the caller advances the writer, it uses that pointer to access the bytes written so that it can maintain a running CRC32 calculation of the data written.

Does this work as intended? I believe that the spans and memories locations are not shifted between calls to GetSpan, GetMemory, and Advance, so I believe it's safe and will always work as expected but I'm not sure.

Have I used the most efficient technique for saving the address of the span or memory, and creating a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` for accessing the data when the writer is advanced?

```cs
public unsafe struct CRC32DelimitedBufferWriter : IBufferWriter<byte>
{
    private readonly IBufferWriter<byte> innerWriter;
    private readonly CRC32Builder crcBuilder;

    private byte* pointer;
    private int bytesWritten;

    public CRC32DelimitedBufferWriter(IBufferWriter<byte> innerWriter)
    {
        this.innerWriter = innerWriter;
        this.crcBuilder = CRC32Builder.CreateInitialized();
        this.bytesWritten = 0;
        this.pointer = (byte*)0;
    }

    public Span<byte> GetSpan(int sizeHint = 0)
    {
        var span = this.innerWriter.GetSpan(sizeHint);
        this.pointer = (byte*)MemoryMarshal.GetReference(span);
        return span;
    }

    public Memory<byte> GetMemory(int sizeHint = 0)
    {
        var memory = this.innerWriter.GetMemory(sizeHint);
        this.pointer = (byte*)memory.Pin().Pointer;
        return memory;
    }

    public void Advance(int count)
    {
        this.crcBuilder.Add(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(this.pointer, count));
        this.innerWriter.Advance(count);
        this.bytesWritten += count;
    }

    public void WriteCRCDelimiter()
    {
        var span = this.innerWriter.GetSpan(9);
        span[0] = 255;
        span.Slice(1).WriteInt(this.bytesWritten);
        span.Slice(5).WriteInt((int)this.crcBuilder.Value);
        this.innerWriter.Advance(9);
        this.crcBuilder.Initialize();
        this.bytesWritten = 0;
    }
}

public static class SpanExtensions
{
    public static void WriteInt(this Span<byte> span, int value)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            span[i] = (byte)value;
            value >>= 8;
        }
    }
}
```